# hgrc extentions in /home folder not recognized

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I added the convert extension (with no path) to my /home/user/.hgrc file, but it is not working:

```
$ hg convert source_r56 source_r56_fixed --filemap exclude.filemap
hg: unknown command 'convert'
'convert' is provided by the following extension:

    convert  import revisions from foreign VCS repositories into Mercurial

use "hg help extensions" for information on enabling extensions
```

I ran "hg help extensions" and realized that none of the enabled extensions in the file are showing as enabled.

I tried setting it in the source_r56/.hg/hgrc as well to no avail.

Update:

```
$ cat ~/.hgrc
[ui]
username = jetimms <jetimms@jetimms>
verbose = True
[extentions]
convert =
progress = 
rebase =
[alias]
ssh = ssh -C
$ cat ./.hg/hgrc
[paths]
default = /home/jetimms/source
[extentions]
convert =
$
```

(BTW: source_r56 was cloned from a repository called "source".)

Perhaps to better answer the question about whether I am having the same problems with other extensions, I have included part of the results from "hg help extensions" regarding disabled extensions. Here I only note the ones listed above in the the ~/.hgrc. As noted in the comments, I have not used any other extensions.

```
$ hg help extensions
Using additional features
...
    disabled extensions:
...
     convert     import revisions from foreign VCS repositories into Mercurial
...
     progress    show progress bars for some actions
...
     rebase      command to move sets of revisions to a different ancestor
$
```

Comment: How did you configure the extension?  Could you provide your `.hgrc`?   Also your project `.hg/hgrc`?  Do you have the same problem with other extensions?  Which mercurial version are you using?

Comment: I updated the above to address your questions regarding file contents and configuration. I have never used other extensions for Hg. I am using Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.6.4). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mispelled the word extensions in your `.hgrc`.  Change `[extentions]` to `[extensions]` and you're set.

Comment: Well, I feel silly now. Funny that I spelled it right in the question above, but not in my files. Anyhow, thanks for your help!